# Extending Flask class as main App

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask and am a bit confused about how to structure my code. So I tried to extend Flask main class as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, ...

class App(Flask):
    def __init__(self, import_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(import_name, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that I am aware of that this may be a completely wrong approach. 

So that when I want to start the app I do:

```
app = App(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This way I can order my methods and routes in the class, but the problem is when using self-decorators:

```
@route('/')
def home(self, context=None):
    context = context or dict()
    return render_template('home.html', **context)
```

Which raises an error as `unresolved reference 'route'`. I guess this is not the way I should be structuring the app. How should I do it instead or how do I get the error fixed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doing this doesn't make sense.  You would subclass `Flask` to change its internal behavior, not to define your routes as class methods.

Instead, you're looking for [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/blueprints/) and the [app factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/appfactories/).  Blueprints divide your views into groups without requiring an app, and the factory creates and sets up the app only when called.

`my_app/users/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('users', __name__, url_prefix='/users')
```

`my_app/users/views.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from my_app.users import bp

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('users/index.html')
```

`my_app/__init__.py`

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # set up the app here
    # for example, register a blueprint
    from my_app.users import bp
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

`run.py`

```
from my_app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Run the dev server with:

```
FLASK_APP=run.py
FLASK_DEBUG=True
flask run
```

If you need access to the app in a view, use `current_app`, just like `request` gives access to the request in the view.

```
from flask import current_app
from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer

@bp.route('/token')
def token():
    s = URLSafeSerializer(current_app.secret_key)
    return s.dumps('secret')
```

---

If you *really* want to define routes as methods of a Flask subclass, you'll need to use [`self.add_url_rule`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) in `__init__` rather than decorating each route locally.

```
class MyFlask(Flask):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.index)

    def index(self):
        return render_template('index.html')
```

The reason `route` (and `self`) won't work is because it's an instance method, but you don't have an instance when you're defining the class.