# How to add route / view function using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to add a "/" url function in class definition,I works fine with common url like "/list/".But it doesn't work with "/"

```py
from flask import Flask,views,url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
class ListView(views.View):
    def dispatch_request(self):
        return 'list view'
    def hello_world(self):#how to add this function in class definition?
        return 'Hello World!'
#app.add_url_rule('/list/',endpoint='list',view_func=ListView.as_view('list'))
app.add_url_rule('/list/',view_func=ListView.as_view("list"))
app.add_url_rule('/',view_func=ListView.hello_world("/"))

with app.test_request_context():
    print(url_for('list'))
with app.test_request_context():
    print(url_for(''))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When add "/" url into my class view definition,I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):#error when add / url in class view function definition.
  File "hello.py", line 10, in <module>
    app.add_url_rule('/',view_func=ListView.hello_world("/"))
  File "W:\cl\venv\flask_web\lib\site-packages\flask-2.0.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\flask\app.py", line 82, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "W:\cl\venv\flask_web\lib\site-packages\flask-2.0.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\flask\app.py", line 1160, in add_url_rule
    endpoint = _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func)
  File "W:\cl\venv\flask_web\lib\site-packages\flask-2.0.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\flask\helpers.py", line 84, in _endpoint_from_view_func
    return view_func.__name__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

How to add an empty url ("/") using class view function?
The following answer from an other similar quesion doesn't work.

```py
class MyFlask(Flask):
    def __init__(self):
        #super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_url_rule('/', view_func=self.index)

    def index(self):
        return "hello world"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance=MyFlask()
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232166/extending-flask-class-as-main-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending Flask class as main App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232166/extending-flask-class-as-main-app)

Comment: No, it dosen't.I try your the method in your link,it doesn't work well\